# Accessing ArcSDE delta tables through Python?

Tags: arcpy, sql, arcgis-pro, python-3

I would like to access delta tables through ArcPy for a QC script that I am improving. Read-only. How could I output a Python dictionary that contains all the rows that were added/deleted/modified between a named version and `DEFAULT` for a particular feature class?

We are currently on an Oracle client, but we will be switching to SQL Server, if there are substantial differences between the two.

Comment: To paraphrase Sigourney Weaver, "There is no ArcSDE, only Enterprise geodatabase."  The mechanism for locating differences between versions with Desktop is the Version Changes utility.  Based on [this GeoNet thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/192508-get-version-change-details-using-arcpy), it seems to be UI-only, not scriptable.

Comment: @Vince is correct that there is no arcpy tool that will allow you to do this directly. You can, however, resolve this information using SQL queries. In practice, you could call your SQL statements via Python and then build the dictionary. Can you clarify what you have already tried and the specific issue(s) you've run into?

Comment: @Radar I haven't tried anything yet because I don't have a lot of experience working outside of the `arcpy` library. I have found [this help doc from ESRI](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010102), and I planned on applying these concepts inside python, probably through `ArcSDESQLExecute`.